# Access char** result from Swift

Tags: c, arrays, swift

In my Swift code I call a C method that returns a `char**` result. How can I coerce that so I have a `[String]` to deal with?

Comment: usually in C, a **null-terminated** `char *` variable can represent a _string_. can you detail a little bit? Hint: `char ** p` and `*p[i]`

Comment: It would probably make more sense to convert `char **` to `[String]`. But more information is needed. Is each `char *` 0-terminated? Is the `char **` NULL-terminated? Who allocates the memory and who is responsible for freeing it? Are the strings constant or do you want to modify the strings from Swift?

Comment: @Martin R: Of course it's [String]. I've corrected the question. See also my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the swift answers ;-) I managed to get it working with

```
let c1 = String.fromCString(row.memory)
let c2 = String.fromCString(row.advancedBy(1).memory)
```

where `row` is actually my `char**`array I got from C. Actually this is a MYSQL_ROW since I want to communicate with a MySQL.

Comment: That assumes that you have NUL-terminated UTF-8 strings. I am not a MySQL expert at all, but according to the documentation the MYSQL_ROW contains pointers to counted byte arrays. Are these necessarily NUL-terminated?

Comment: I tried it by example and it did work. IF (and I guess so) the MySQL guy did a good job the strings should be NUL-terminated in addition to anything else. That's what I'd call robust programming.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to handle a `char **` it means that you are dealing with a pointer to a pointer.
As Sourav Ghosh said, C language don't have *string* data type properly.
Instead of it you must declare a pointer to character, or `char *`. 
It means youre pointing to memory address that can have a single character ( 1 byte ) or an array of them.

Here's an example from how can you handle it

```
char *myString;

myString = &swift();
printf("My string is %s", myString);
```

Good Luck

Comment: I don't know Swift, but the OP's question says he's calling C _from_ Swift and wants to coerce the `char**` it contains into a `[[String]]`, which presumably is a Swift type.

Comment: TripeHound is right. You got it the wrong way around.

Comment: I got it @ThomasKilian, sorry for the mistake